# Amazon FPS CBUI Return Url Validation - PHP

Tags: php, amazon-fps

I'm trying to run through the Amazon FPS quickstart guide for PHP and am having trouble verifying the return url provided by the CBUI.

Here is the url:

```
http://local-screen.com/wp-content/plugins/lclscrn_projects/amazon_fps/FPS/ReturnUrlVerificationSampleCode.php?tokenID=N1G9E5I7BH72563866UZ23YZ1X1AL9AZ2A9291Q1PKDATS8R7BLZ6Y7LEHY2QRHS&signatureMethod=RSA-SHA1&status=SC&signatureVersion=2&signature=WbBPFQku5BA67CR9vWr664eLNDahErYWZM6GrOYTnlDmLZf0rBm0XATrGPLgj5V94GsP0n%2BJ0uye%0A0MRZ3gastZX9M0cjbaPBcCjW1ydt%2BtCiatd%2BjQA6ZRs7XD%2BmWMqHVT3b4eY5WXKHHHQIvp4xLjJY%0AxuwtLf4MaYuiATtdnCY%3D&certificateUrl=https%3A%2F%2Ffps.sandbox.amazonaws.com%2Fcerts%2F090911%2FPKICert.pem%3FrequestId%3Dbjyk7pqb789b33qxg4h9lx8kn8ijplnc5pow0ycey00olslowmv&expiry=01%2F2018&callerReference=%241%24yo8s
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Verifying return url signed using signature v2 .... 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Amazon_FPS_SignatureException' with message 'Certificate could not be verified by the FPS service' in /home/content/85/9687085/html/wp-content/plugins/lclscrn_projects/amazon_fps/FPS/SignatureUtilsForOutbound.php:103 Stack trace: #0 /home/content/85/9687085/html/wp-content/plugins/lclscrn_projects/amazon_fps/FPS/SignatureUtilsForOutbound.php(50): Amazon_FPS_SignatureUtilsForOutbound->validateSignatureV2(Array, 'http://local-sc...', 'GET') #1 /home/content/85/9687085/html/wp-content/plugins/lclscrn_projects/amazon_fps/FPS/ReturnUrlVerificationSampleCode.php(93): Amazon_FPS_SignatureUtilsForOutbound->validateRequest(Array, 'http://local-sc...', 'GET') #2 /home/content/85/9687085/html/wp-content/plugins/lclscrn_projects/amazon_fps/FPS/ReturnUrlVerificationSampleCode.php(97): Amazon_FPS_ReturnUrlVerificationSampleCode::test() #3 {main} thrown in /home/content/85/9687085/html/wp-content/plugins/lclscrn_projects/amazon_fps/FPS/SignatureUtilsForOutbound.php on line 103
```

Here is the function that gets the variables and calls the validation page:

```
public static function test() {

                $aws_access_key = self::$aws_access_key;
                $aws_secret_key = self::$aws_secret_key;

                $utils = new Amazon_FPS_SignatureUtilsForOutbound($aws_access_key, $aws_secret_key);

                /* Verification of an return url signed using signature version 2.*/

                // New parameters sent in return url signed using signature v2
                $params["certificateUrl"] = self::$certificate_url;
                $params["signature"] = self::$signature;
                $params["signatureMethod"] = self::$signature_method;
                $params["signatureVersion"] = self::$signature_version;

                // foreach ($params as $param) {
                //         echo $param;
                //         echo '<br/><br/>';
                // }
                // echo self::$return_url;
                // return;


                $urlEndPoint = self::$return_url; //Your return url end point. 
                print "Verifying return url signed using signature v2 ....\n";
                //return url is sent as a http GET request and hence we specify GET as the http method.
                //Signature verification does not require your secret key
                print "Is signature correct: " . $utils->validateRequest($params, $urlEndPoint, "GET") . "\n";
    }
```

I also have the output of the foreach loop above which I can PM if somebody needs it. I just don't understand why I can't validate this url. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Nick

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the PHP sample code from Amazon as well, and was running into the exact same error message.

**Solution**

**Requirement 1:** The value of `HttpParameters` that you pass in the VerifySignature request must have parameters in the same order as passed to your return URL by Amazon's UI. So instead of manually fetching each GET parameter as Amazon's sample code does, simply use the `$_GET` object as the value of the `$parameters` variable in `SignatureUtilsForOutbound.php`.

**Requirement 2:** You need to test from a box that is accessible on the Internet. You will always get this error if you're testing from localhost.

Comment: Requirement 2 isn't quite true. You just have to use valid url, like `http://127.0.0.1/`, `http://example.com/` or something. `localhost` won't work. Check [this link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=265110)